DataGridView extremely slow updating thousands of cells
I have a DataGridView that is populated with around ~30,000 rows. Only two columns.
The user can only edit the first column cell of each row. When they finish editing this cell, all other rows that have a matching first column cell value must be updated to the new cell and a style has to be applied to just that cell.
I am doing this in the CellValueChanged event like so:
private void SamplesTable_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)private void SamplesTable_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (_isEditing)
    {
        return;
    }

    _isEditing = true; // don't want this function to be called every time if updating multiple cells at once

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in SensorsTable.Rows)
    {
        // only change cells whose value matched the old cell's value that caused this event
        if (!row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim().Equals(_oldValue, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            continue;
        }

        row.Cells[0].Value = newValue;
        row.Cells[0].Style = cellStyle; // cellStyle is just DataGridViewCellStyle() { BackColor = Color.Yellow };
    }

    _isEditing = false;
}

This takes ~10 minutes when affecting thousands of rows. I've tried suspending the layout before the loop and then resuming it after but didn't notice a difference.
One thing to note is I am manually adding all the rows from a list, no binding involved.

update the datasource, datagridview is notoriously slow

Use data binding. Also enable double buffering.

Displaying large amounts of data takes up a long loading times and takes up a lot of RAM. The easiest solution, divide large data into small pages with pagination and add navigation to move between small pages. This will speed up your data when loading and saving RAM. Look at here https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/10/17/c-pure-pagination-logic-in-c-aspnet

That's not the correct way to apply cell styles. You either want to override the OnCellFormatting method, e.g. protected override void OnCellFormatting(DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e) or add the corresponding event listener, e.g. dgv.CellFormatting += ...;

Then use the DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e object itself to apply the style using the e.CellStyle property.

By doing it the way you are doing it, it results in unsharing all the rows, which is why your code is slow.

The CellValueChanged is raised when the Value property changes. And you're changing the property in the event which fires the event again and again. 30,000+ ^ 2 times. Use a bool field to enter the loop only once. Or -= & += the handler. Or better use a data source as mentioned.

You need to change the data first and then trigger the graphical change exactly once rather than changing the style for each cells that you are to affect.
So, in SamplesTable_CellValueChanged make sure that you override the DataSource of SensorsTable (see an example here: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/192278/Changing-the-datasource-in-a-DataGridView-after-ce).
